# Menu item bumped down

Tags: html, css

My menu has one item bumped down for no apparent reason.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
    My first Site
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
  <li><a href="My first site.html"><H1>Home</H1></a></li>
  <li><a href="Testimonials.html"><H1>Testimonials</H1></a></li>
  <li><a href="Schedule.html"><H1>Schedule</H1></li>
  <li><a href="About.html"><H1>About</H1></a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact.html"><H1>Contact</H1></a></li>
</ul>
    </body>
    <style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



    </style>
</html>
```

---

Here is the result:

[image]

I'm using Chrome

Comment: You forgot a </a> closing tag in your `Schedule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added closing tag with snippet

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>My first Site</title></head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="My first site.html"><h1>Home</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="Testimonials.html"><h1>Testimonials</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="Schedule.html"><h1>Schedule</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html"><h1>About</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html"><h1>Contact</h1></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```